# VBA if cell blank, delete row, if no cells blank, end sequence

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I think I need a loop function for this but i'm not sure how to go about it.

The task for this is to see if a specific column is blank, then to delete that row. But sometimes there is no blank cells and i am getting a end debug error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim lr As Long
Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet
Set shCurrentWeek = AciveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

'Delete Row
shCurrentWeek.Range("B4:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Daniel Cook is right, you could use `On Error Resume Next`, here is another way of going about it, since using `On Error Resume Next` is really a last resort option in VBA (IMO).

The code below checks for blanks before it tries to use the `SpecialCells` method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim lr As Long
Dim shCurrentWeek As Worksheet

Set shCurrentWeek = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Current Week")
lr = shCurrentWeek.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(shCurrentWeek.Range("B4:B" & lr)) <> 0 Then

    shCurrentWeek.Range("B4:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: No, On Error Resume Next is the quick and dirty solution. It's what you do when you just want it to work now, and don't want to spend the time or don't have the time, to figure out how to avoid the error altogether. That being said, this certainly works so +1.

Answer (score 3):

How about just putting `on error resume next` right before your `Delete` line? LIke this:

```
On error resume next
shCurrentWeek.Range("B4:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

I'm assuming you don't care if it fails, so there's no need to do error trapping. This will keep an error message from displaying if there are no cells returned from your call to `SpecialCells`.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, such a easy fix... sigh. Thnx.

Comment: +1 Always avoid range loops. remember to reset the error handler though on the next line

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code I use for that type of operation.

> Sub ClearBlank()
>
> > Dim i As Long
> >
> > > For i = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row To 8 Step -1
> > >       If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Then Rows(i).Delete
> > >
> > > Next i
> >
> > End Sub

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not used VBA before today so I'm sure there is a neater way...but this code will delete any row with at least one empty cell. It assumes that you have a header row and that the first column is used for IDs so these cells are not 'looked at'.

The nice thing about this script is that it works for **any size of spreadsheet** so you don't need to hard-code values each time:

```
Sub DeleteIncompleteRows()
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Dim deleted As Integer
deleted = 0
Dim actualRow As Integer
Dim totalRows As Integer
Dim totalCols As Integer
totalRows = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
totalCols = Application.CountA(Range("1:1"))

For row = 2 To totalRows
actualRow = row - deleted
For col = 2 To totalCols
If ActiveSheet.Cells(actualRow, col).Value = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Rows(actualRow).Delete
deleted = deleted + 1
Exit For
End If
Next col
Next row
End Sub
```

All the best,

Scott